# How to create a javascript sdk with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would appreciate a direction as I am lost and cannot find any source that explains how I can create a global function that my customers can use. I have multiple REST API that customers can use however I am trying to create a javascrtipt SDK so they can simply call a function and everything else is taken care of.

For example, all the user has to do is import a script in head tag and then use my variable across the app to invoke functions. Like how stripe provides SDK.

```
Stripe.getCustomer('pass some data id');
```

I have a similar need, where user can save data to DB.

```
myapp.saveDatatoDb(data).then(response => {
});
```

the saveToDB will take care of calling an API and storing the information. Where do I get started?

Comment: What does this have to do with react?

Comment: Just write the function that you want your users to be able to call, and put it in your library script.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do but not able to expose it.

I have a Js file that is served over my website and I am adding this simple function export function pluskaran(a, b) {
  return a + b;
} in there. Cant access this

Comment: If you `export` the function, then your website application will need to `import` it to use it (which is a good thing!). If you just want to include a `<script>` that will create global variables, you'll need to write a normal script without `export`.